# How can I get rid of the blank space under the website?

Tags: html, web

OK, so im working on [this](http://www.home.thundaworks.com/) website for a friend. The homepage looks pretty good but im having a problem with the 4 pages that are linked at the top. Every time I click on them and they load but there is a big blank space at the bottom of the page. Its not a huge deal but I think it looks funny. Anyone have any idea whats wrong with it? Did I mess up a line of code (probably), and if so, where would that line of code be?

I want the page to stretch all the way to the bottom of the browser windows. Any help would be great, even if you can just point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you can try at doctype.com

Comment: Please consider usability as well as "looks".  my large fonts completely destroy your layout, and I notice all the "info" is mocked up. 

I suggest starting with the info you are trying to present to the users. Only after you have organized it well should you start putting together the graphics.

Comment: Thanks people for your help. It fixed the problem. 

@Joe I understand what you are saying, it just that I didn't build the site. Im just helping a friend update the content. Great tip anyway though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try changing the main table's height from 86% to 100%.